# An entire function is a polynomial in z if either of it's real or imaginary parts are polynomials in x,y.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove the above result.

What I thought is that if either of them is a polynomial the so will the other part by C-R equations. But itself cannot gaurantee that f has to be a polynomial in z.

Or otherwise we may start by writing the power series expansion of f with infinitely many terms and somehow contradicting the given condition.

Kindly help!!
Any hints will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is an entire function and $\Im f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $f^{(n+1)}$ is an entire, real function, so it is constant. Then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Brilliant! ${}{}$